# JAX-WS Separate Instance For Separate User

Tags: java, servlets, jax-ws, rmi

Is there a way to run separate instances for each connection -or let's say user-, like rmi, via JAX-WS?

Comment: JAX-WS or JAX-RS? The question was initially about RS, why did you change it?

Comment: I miswote it. While I was writing it, I am looking for JAX-*. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is stateless, therefore each request is on its own. The instance of the service is just one, and that's good.

If you want to store session information (i.e. separate data for each client) you have a couple of options that let you identify each subsequent request as belonging to the same user:

- create your own solution - let the client pass a token that identifies his session, and load that session from an in-memory or db-persisted `Map<String, ...>`.
- use OAuth

Comment: I've seen OAuth with REST, and SAML with both JAXWS and REST, but not OAuth and JAXWS. Do you have any quick references for using OAuth with JAXWS?

Comment: nope. But it shouldn't make a difference. In fact, the question was originally about JAX-RS, then the author eited it, I don't know why. Bbut it should work with ws as well